# NBitcoin ExtPubKey

Tags: bitcoin

Which part/format of the ExpPubKey created with NBitcoin should I give my transaction payments key generator or set on a website as default to generate transaction payment addresses. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: StackOverflow is for code questions.  This question seems to be more about computing in general.  Please update your question to show how it is coding related, or perhaps ask on [su].

Comment: This is a coding question, just a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question a little vague, so first I give you a general answer:
I have written a class that handles correctly the key generation and storage for you: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1096320/HiddenBitcoin-High-level-Csharp-Bitcoin-wallet-lib) is an article about it.

If I do not misunderstand you, what you want is to to generate the keys with JavaScript in browser, so you can only give a string to it.
The thing is you do not give the `ExtPubKey`, you give its wallet import format.

```
ExtKey seedPrivateKey = new ExtKey();
ExtPubKey seedPublicKey = seedPrivateKey.Neuter();
BitcoinExtPubKey seedMainNetPublickKey = seedPublicKey.GetWif(Network.Main);
```

You can get the string by calling `seedMainNetPublickKey.ToString()`